# Indexing a ranged partition Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I want to index a partition of my table, I'm not sure how to do it and I don't have access to my database atm.

The database is Oracle 11.
Would my code work?

```
CREATE TABLE MARKET.PARTTABLE
(
  EXTRACT_DATE   DATE                   NOT NULL,
  LOAD_ID    NUMBER(10)                 NOT NULL,
  LOAD_DATE  DATE                       NOT NULL,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)              NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (EXTRACT_DATE)
(   
    PARTITION PDEFAULT VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    NOLOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE MARKET_DAT
    PCTFREE    0
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
CREATE INDEX NAME_PARTTABLE ON PARTTABLE(NAME)
)
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> ORA-14020: this physical attribute may not be specified for a table
>   partition

This indicates that I have a formatting issue, but I actually don't find any helpful documentation to index partition (or maybe I'm just too stupid to understand them).

EDIT:
I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE MARKET.PARTTABLE
(
  EXTRACT_DATE   DATE                   NOT NULL,
  LOAD_ID    NUMBER(10)                 NOT NULL,
  LOAD_DATE  DATE                       NOT NULL,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)              NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (EXTRACT_DATE)
(   
    PARTITION PDEFAULT VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    NOLOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE MARKET_DAT
    PCTFREE    0
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
)
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
CREATE INDEX NAME_PARTTABLE ON PARTTABLE(NAME)
```

It worked, but I'm not sure if the index is now on the partition or if it is on the whole table. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Are you really asking someone to test your code? I can give you a going rate if that's the case.

Comment: Well I'm not at work right now so I can't access the database but my colleague asked me to help. I would be happy with the proper syntax for creating a partition index.

Comment: https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler

Comment: Thank you, that actually helps. But I get the error 
ORA-14020: this physical attribute may not be specified for a table partition
which doesn't help me much, I will test some more.. thanks

Comment: I tested a different solution which doesn't throw an error, but I don't know if I now just indexed the table or if I really indexed the partitions. Could you maybe help me out some? I'm sorry for not testing beforehand

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an Oracle expert, I just edit posts here sometimes. I'm not sure about your question about indexed partitions. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second statement did not in fact create an `INDEX` on the partition.
Partitioned indexes should  either be defined as `LOCAL` or `GLOBAL`.

Since  what you are trying to create is a *Non-Prefixed index*( The leftmost column(s) of the index is not the  partition key), better option is to go with a `LOCAL INDEX`

```
CREATE INDEX NAME_PARTTABLE ON PARTTABLE(NAME) LOCAL;
```

> ..but I'm not sure if the index is now on the partition or if
>   it is on the whole table.

You may query the data dictionary view `ALL_PART_INDEXES` or `USER_PART_INDEXES` to check for your index name. Normal non-partitioned indexes aren't shown from these views.

```
select * from USER_PART_INDEXES where index_name='NAME_PARTTABLE';
```

[Partitioned Tables And Indexes](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/partitioned-tables-and-indexes)

Comment: thank you, I got it to work like you described, but didn't see your answer. I accepted as the correct solution.